# How to run a pulled images - docker

Tags: docker, docker-run, docker-pull

I'm trying to run a pulled image without any success.
I pulled an image from AWS using the Image URI.

when I run `docker images` I can see my pulled image:

```
REPOSITORY                                           TAG             IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alpine                                               3.9             055936d39205        3 weeks ago         5.53MB
24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools    dab-1.1.0slim   f994713b61cb        3 weeks ago         110MB
ubuntu                                               16.04           a3551444fc85        5 weeks ago         119MB
anapsix/alpine-java                                  8               745575fbfe52        3 months ago        126MB
```

I'm new at dockers, but from what I understand after pulling no need to build it, just run it but when I tried to run it like so: `docker run 24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools` I get the below message:

```
Unable to find image '24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

So I tried to build it like so: `docker build -t 24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools`
and got the message:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.
```

What is the problem?
How can I run a pulled image from AWS?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There isnt any image with tag "latest"
Try running using the tag "dab-1.1.0slim"

```
docker run 24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools:dab-1.1.0slim
```

Or else you could run the docker image using image id

```
docker run -i -t f994713b61cb
```

for more info on docker run command check out 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Thanks! That worked. After running the image, I'm suppose to be inside the container , right? If I run `docker ps` I should see my running container?

Comment: It seems to run but exits immediately form the container and not showing when I type `docker ps`. Any idea why?

Comment: no idea, create a new thread with all the logs from the container.

Comment: Wait, I'm totally confused, when I pull an image from AWS for example, I don't have the dockerfile itself, right? To run the container do I need the dockerfile itself? If yes, how can I get it?

Comment: If you've pulled the image using `docker pull whatever`, then using the `docker images` command will list the images you have downloaded.  From there, you can run the image (without needing a dockerfile) via `docker run REPOSITORY`, `docker run IMAGEID`, or `docker run REPOSITORY:TAG`.  (words in all-caps refer to the corresponding column from `docker images` output)

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple command

```
docker run -d -p [PORT_ON_YOUR_BROWSER]:[PORT_ON_CONTAINER] <Image ID>

docker run -d -p 8080:80 <Image ID>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I usually go through these steps:

```bash
    # download an image 
    > docker pull danielszabo99/microbin

    # list your images 
    > docker image ls
    
    REPOSITORY               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
    danielszabo99/microbin   latest    c6669d651bfe   37 hours ago   77.8MB

    
    > docker run danielszabo99/microbin

    # this image runs on port 8080 so we can also map it to a localhost 
    # port for browser access (local:remote)
    # docker run --publish 8080:8080  danielszabo99/microbin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the image by docker image id
When building the image you need to add `.` at the end of your command as for an example 
`docker build -t 24325.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lm/rd/tools .` and you need to have the `Dockerfile` (Assume you have).

Comment: I don't have it....I assumed that if I pulled it I have it. How can I get the dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Adding some information that hasn't been covered above for anyone else.

Checking what docker images are available with `docker ls -al` will add the image `name` to the terminal output allowing `docker run name` which is similar to using the `image ID` Sree has given in his answer. However, docker default names are human-readable and are created automatically when the container is built.

Answer (score -6):

If you want to run docker image which pulled from the remote repository just use the **IMAGE ID** instead of Image name (Repository).

```
docker run -i -t f994713b61cb /bin/bash
```