# docker run gives Error: '' is not a valid port number

Tags: docker, docker-run

I am new to docker, trying to run a pulled docker image.

`docker images` gives this:

```
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
openmined/grid-network   development         f760520b2550        8 days ago          785MB
openmined/grid-node      development         89a4d0202703        8 days ago          3.48GB
```

I ran the pulled images following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413414/how-to-run-a-pulled-images-docker), by using command: `docker run -i -t f760520b2550` but found this error:

```
Error: '' is not a valid port number.
```

I tried playing with the flags like `docker run -i -t f760520b2550 -p 8080:8080`, but didn't help.
I have only installed docker recently and have done no changes in configurations. Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -i -t f760520b2550`

Comment: It gives the same error but adding another flag `-d` solves the issue. I used the command `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -i -t f760520b2550` and it worked fine. I still don't see anything on 127.0.0.1:8080.

Can you please tell me how can I `docker-compose up` it? I am following instructions from [here](https://github.com/OpenMined/PyGrid). Do I need to write my own docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I created a docker-compose.yml file as this: https://pastebin.com/jJuiuwdF and received the same error(https://pastebin.com/UtqYVpws) on doing `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem working with a docker image. What worked for me was making the following change in the dockerfile to build the docker image with
`--bind 0.0.0.0:8080` instead of `--bind :$PORT`

`--bind :$PORT` does work in a cloud build, but doesn't work in a docker run.

Don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

To expose ports using `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'
services:
  grid-network:
    image: openmined/grid-network:development
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8001:8001"
```

Then `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you can just bind port to 8080 like I am giving an example

*In Dockerfile:*

FROM python:3.7

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD gunicorn --workers=1 --**bind 0.0.0.0:8080** application:application

*And then in terminal use :* (Pass your image id in place of IMAGE ID below)

docker run -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 IMAGE ID